# What is the difference between the principle of virtual work and the principle of virtual displacement?

Tags: classical-mechanics, work, coordinate-systems, definition

When I read Reddy's book, *"Energy Principles and Variational Methods in Applied Mechanics"*, Chapter 5.1. I am confused with the two jargons "the principle of virtual displacement" and "the principle of virtual work". They are used interchangeably without clarification. Could someone explain the difference between them?

Comment: The are the same thing.

Comment: I thought so. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Loosely, work is force times displacement (more precisely $W=\int \vec F.d\vec r$ ).

Virtual work is force times virtual displacement( $dW= \vec F.d\vec r$ ).

It is regarded as "virtual", because the object does not actually move, but we imagine it moving an infinitesimal displacement $d\vec r$, which we call virtual displacement.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer from Reddy's book. "the principle of virtual work" and "the principle of virtual displacement" refer to the same thing while "the principle of virtual force" and "the principle of complementary virtual work" refer to one other principle.